# removeEventListener function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, removeeventlistener

So I have 3 game tile divs with class '.tile', after a unit is selected I then am looping through the tiles to add an event listener to create a hover effect when they are moused over so they know where the unit can be placed.

This first part works fine, though I suspect it could be messy, so then I added a reset button with class '.reset' to remove the event handlers/hover effect when it is pushed to start over.

The reset button removeEventListeners are not working, however, even though it has the same parameters. The hover effect is still active. I have tried it with and without the 'true' capture parameter as well and it doesn't seem to matter. Any help is appreciated.

```
    const p1InfP = document.getElementById('p1InfP')

    p1InfP.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        p1InfP.style.border = "1px solid black"
        place(tiles)
    })

    const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile')

    function place(array){
        for(let i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        tiles[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {tiles[i].style.border = "1px solid #0000FF"},true)
        tiles[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {tiles[i].style.border = "1px solid transparent"},true)
        }
    }

    function remove(array){
        for(let i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        tiles[i].removeEventListener('mouseover', () => {tiles[i].style.border = "1px solid #0000FF"},true)
        tiles[i].removeEventListener('mouseout', () => {tiles[i].style.border = "1px solid transparent"},true)
        }
    }

    const reset = document.getElementById('reset')
    
    reset.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        p1InfP.style.border = "1px solid transparent"
        remove(tiles)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener function that `removeEventListener` should remove must be **same**, not a equal, redefined function.

```js
const p1InfP = document.getElementById('p1InfP')

p1InfP.addEventListener('click', () => {
  p1InfP.style.border = "1px solid black"
  place(tiles)
})

const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile')

const onMouseoverEvent = e => {
  e.currentTarget.style.border = "1px solid #0000FF";
}

const onMouseoutEvent = e => {
  e.currentTarget.style.border = "1px solid transparent";
}

function place(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseoverEvent, true)
    tiles[i].addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseoutEvent, true)
  }
}

function remove(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].removeEventListener('mouseover', onMouseoverEvent, true)
    tiles[i].removeEventListener('mouseout', onMouseoutEvent, true)
  }
}

const reset = document.getElementById('reset')

reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  p1InfP.style.border = "1px solid transparent"
  remove(tiles)
})
```

```html
<div id="p1InfP">foo</div>

<div class="tile">bar</div>
<div class="tile">bar</div>
<div class="tile">bar</div>

<div id="reset">baz</div>
```